# How to use $http into constant

Tags: angularjs

**EDIT: This question is deprecated.** Please see [How to set a variable from an $http call then use it in the rest of the application WITHOUT making the whole application asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129638/how-to-set-a-variable-from-an-http-call-then-use-it-in-the-rest-of-the-applicat) instead.

In my constant, I need to read from a local file. The way I've seen to do that is `$http.get('localfile.ext').then ...`

It's telling me `$http` is undefined. The [documentation](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-constant-recipe) says constant is special, services are available in a constant.

```
angular.module('myApp').constant(
  'test',
  ['xml','$http',
  (function ($http, x2js) {
    $http.get('web.config').then(function (response) {
      var appSettings = [];
      /*setting up the response*/
      var json = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
      var url = '' /* get url from json */;
    });
    // Use the variable in your constants
    return {
      URL: url
    }
  })()]);
```

**EDIT:**

Ok [this documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection) says you can't use DI in a constant. But I need to use $http to get a value and use it to set a constant. So how can I do it or what would be a alternative that allows me to read the value anywhere in the app once it is set?

Comment: By the way the `['xml','$http',` and `($http, x2js)` have to be in the same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Build a constant**

Build the confguration into Angular `constant` with build system. There are [grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant) and [gulp-ng-constant](https://github.com/guzart/gulp-ng-constant).

**Resolve the dependency**

Use ng-route or ui-router `resolve` to resolve config dependency for all routes.

**Defer bootstrap**

Defer bootstrapping process to resolve global dependencies before the app is there with [angular-deferred-bootstrap](https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap).

**Use synchronous request**

Synchronous requests are blocking, and bad, and blocking... they are bad also. Either raw `XMLHttpRequest` or `jQuery.ajax` can be used (`$http` doesn't support synchronous requests).

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
  var config;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'configfile', false);
  xhr.send();
  if (xhr.status == '200') {
    config = xhr.responseText;
  }

  $provide.constant('config', config);
});
```

Comment: Build a constant ended up being way easier than doing asp.net server side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I've generally done is to generate the code for the constant on the server. As opposed to having the constant populated by some call back to the server.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class JavascriptConstantsHelper
{
    public static string GetConstantsJavascriptFile()
    {
        var constantsCollectionModel = new JObject();

        constantsCollectionModel.Add("version", CoreAssembly.Version.ToString());


        const string outputTemplate = @"
            (function() {
                'use strict';

                window.myModule.constant('constantsCollection', function() {
                    return {constantsCollection};
                });
            })();";

        return outputTemplate.Replace("{constantsCollection}", constantsCollectionModel.ToString());
    } 
}
```

The controller could look like this then

```
public class JavascriptController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetConstants()
    {
        return Content(JavascriptConstantsHelper.GetConstantsJavascriptFile(), "application/javascript");
    }
}
```

The script tag would then look something like this

```
<script src="/Javascript/GetConstants"></script>
```

Comment: The constant that I need is the url of the mvc rest api server, which is not this project but another one. However, this angular project does happen to be a .Net MVC project, which right now just has static content (js/css/html). I do not know how to wire your answer up.

Comment: I added a controller example. You would then reference the controller path in a <script> tag

Comment: One of the keys to this is to capture the module reference in a property of the `window` object. `window.myModule = window.angular.module('myModule', []);` Then make sure your app creation is included prior to the script tag in my example.

Comment: For what you are trying to do in your initial question, the `GetConstantsJavascriptFile()` method would handle whatever values you are trying to retrieve with the `$http.get('web.config')` call. You would need to do this for any constants that require information from some source on the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91117/discussion-between-josh-russo-and-toddmo).

Comment: @toddmo If could mark my answer as correct for the way you were initially attempting to solve it, that would be awesome :o)

Comment: Unfortunately this ended up being overkill for one setting. See my answer. It's a good solution in some cases though, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity sake, here's what I tried first, using Russo's answer as a guide.

However, it added 172 files and 19 MB to the build, so I decided on the other answer. This would not be so bad if I was going to add extensive asp.net server side functionality to the app. But, incrementally, for one setting, it was overkill.

**web.config**

```xml
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RestApiUrl" value="http://localhost/MyWebApiServer/api/"/>
  </appSettings>
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="api/settings"></script>
```

**Controllers/SettingsController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace MyWebSite
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class SettingsController : Controller
  {
    // GET: api/settings
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
      var jObject = new JObject();
      foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
        jObject.Add(key, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]);
      return Content(
        string.Format(@"'use strict'; angular.module('myApp').constant('appSettings', {0});", 
                      jObject), 
        "application/javascript");
    }
  }
}
```

**api.js** *(which WAS my existing constant for api constants. Now it's a factory)*

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('api', 
  ["appSettings",
    function (appSettings) {
      return {
        URL: appSettings.RestApiUrl,
        /* other settings */
      }
    }
  ]
);
```