# How to set a variable from an $http call then use it in the rest of the application WITHOUT making the whole application asynchronous

Tags: angularjs

I have this data

```
{
  "config": {
    "RESTAPIURL": "http://myserver/myrestsite"
  }
}
```

and  I have this factory that reads that data

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('api',
  ["$http", "$q",
  function ($http, $q) {

    function _getConfiguration() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('/scripts/constants/config.json')
      .success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function (data, status) {
        deferred.reject(data, status);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function _restApiUrl() {
      // this doesn't work either. _getConfiguration() doesn't resolve here.
      return _getConfiguration().RESTAPIURL + '/api/';
    }

    return {
      URL: _restApiUrl
    }
  }
  ]
);
```

Then to use it

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('AuthService', function ($http, $q, api,NotificationService) {

    function _get(creds) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({method: 'GET', url: api.URL() + api.AUTH, headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic '+creds}
        })
        .success(function (data, status, results, headers) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            NotificationService.redirect(status);
            deferred.reject(data, status);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        get:_get
    };
});
```

So when I'm using it I am doing `api.URL()` and it's not working.

It used to be hard coded URL so to call it used to be `api.URL`. I really don't want to go through the whole app and convert everything to `api.URL().then(...)`. That would suck.

So how can I nail down this value as a "property" instead of an asynchronous promise that has to be called over and over?

Call it once, fine. Get the value. Put it somewhere. Use the value. Don't ever call the `$http` again after that.

**EDIT**

This is turning up to be one of the most successful questions I've ever asked, and I am gratefully going through each answer in turn. Thank each one of you.

Comment: To avoid having to handle everything in an asyc way take a look at ui-router and how it resolves promises before state changes. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Is this api.URL() purely used for loading data from a server? As in, you don't intend to show the actual value across your website?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825706/angularjs-load-config-on-app-start#answer-22825996. Most common way ive seen suggested is loading your data, setting your variables then manually bootstrapping your app.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia, I respect your reputation, but I am sorry, I totally don't see how that relates to what I'm trying to do. Can you provide an example that connects the dots?

Comment: @ste2425, thanks, but that requires major changes to all my services. Going along with that example, can you see a way to load `data.contacts` in one place instead of in each and every service, and do it one time? (then set $rootScope) or something)

Comment: @GavinvanGent, it's the url to the rest site. All the services of the angular web site then need to use it to call the various api of the rest site. Thanks!

Comment: @toddmo You have stuff X that your app needs, but that stuff X needs to be requested from the server at different times for different reasons. You end up with a bunch of services that just return promises that resolve to stuff X. When you switch to resolving on state changes then you have stuff X already downloaded. It's now data that can be injected into child states, directives and controllers. There is no more need to use promises since ui-router resolved those promises for you. You could create an abstract state called "users" that resolves the user creds and after can inject that data.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia, That is cool! So on other S/O questions where they say "you can't do sync $http in angular", you can go score up some points by bringing this up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a bit to what @ThinkingMedia was saying in the comment, with `ui-router` when defining controllers you can add a `resolve` parameter.

In it you can specify some promises that **have** to resolve before the controller is instantiated, thus you are always sure that the config object is available to the controller or other services that the controller is using.

You can also have parent/child controllers in `ui-router` so you could have a `RootController` that resolves the config object and all other controllers inheriting from RootController

```
.state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
    controller: 'RootController',
    resolve:{
      config: ['api', function(api){
        return api.initialize();
      }       
    }
  });
```

and your api factory:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('api',
  ["$http", "$q",
  function ($http, $q) {
    var _configObject = null;

    function initialize() {
      return $http.get('/scripts/constants/config.json')
      .then(function (data) {
          _configObject = data;
          return data;
      });
    }

    // you can call this in other services to get the config object. No need to initialize again
    function getConfig() {
      return _configObject;
    }

    return {
      initialize: initialize,
      getConfig: getConfig
    }
  }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Bra! Shit works! (My `getConfig` is `URL`). Do you think there's any way to make it so I can just say `api.URL` or am I stuck with `api.URL()`?

Comment: you are stuck with api.url() :). Have you thought about setting the url variable from the server when the html is generated? It would save you a call to the server.

Comment: You should probably add another question with an example ... it's pretty difficult to give an answer like this ..

Comment: I figured out how to do one resolve depending on another as per [this article](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c)

Answer (score 1):

I would pass a callback to the getURL method, and save the URL when it returns. Then I would attach any subsequent requests to that callback. Here I am assuming that you are doing something similar with `api.AUTH` that you don't have a reference to in your code.

Pass a callback to the `getURL` method in the `api` service.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('api', ["$http", "$q",

function ($http, $q) {

    function _getConfiguration() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/scripts/constants/config.json')
            .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
            .error(function (data, status) {
            deferred.reject(data, status);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        getURL: function (cb) {
            var that = this;
            if (that.URL) {
                return cb(that.URL);
            }

            _.getConfiguration().then(function (data) {
                that.URL = data.config.RESTAPIURL + "/api";
                cb(that.URL);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

And in your `AuthService`, wrap your `_get` inside a callback like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AuthService', function ($http, $q, api, NotificationService) {

    function _get(creds) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var getCallback = function (url) {

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url + api.AUTH,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + creds
                }
            })
                .success(function (data, status, results, headers) {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                NotificationService.redirect(status);
                deferred.reject(data, status);
            });
        };
        api.getURL(getCallback);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        get: _get
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see how this would work. However it's more intrusive in the consuming services than having to change `URL` to `URL()`. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you initialize the factory when the app is loading and put the variable onto another property? Something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('api', ["$http", "$q",
  function ($http, $q) {
    // store URL in a variable within the factory
    var _URL;

    function _initFactory() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('/scripts/constants/config.json')
      .success(function (data) {

        // Set your variable after the data is received
        _URL = data.RESTAPIURL;
        deferred.resolve(data);

      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function getURL() {
        return _URL;
    }

    return {
      initFactory: _initFactory,
      URL: getURL
    }
  }
  ]
);


// While the app is initializing a main controller, or w/e you may do, run initFactory
//...
api.initFactory().then(
  // may not need to do this if the URL isn't used during other initialization
)
//...

// then to use the variable later
function _get(creds) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({method: 'GET', url: api.URL + api.AUTH, headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+creds}
    })
    .success(function (data, status, results, headers) {
        deferred.resolve(results);
    })
    return deferred.promise;
 }
```

Comment: This won't work, what if the http call takes 3 seconds? The app will be done initializing long before that

Comment: @sirrocco That's what my comment after `api.initFactory().then(` is about. During initialization it would have to do this asynchronously if other things depend on it.

Comment: The return statement from the api factory, which sets the `URL` property, happens before `URL` variable has a value. It's called during the compile phase. Therefore, the `URL` property is always `undefined`. Try it if you want to in JSFiddle and see if you get that result.

Comment: @toddmo Good point. That's hardly an issue though, it simply needs to go into a getter. Edited

Comment: Ok, here's where this approach is broken. Not saying it can't be fixed. But MainCtrl is not the only entry point into the application. Any refresh on a particular page blows away `api.URL`. MainCtrl is not a sure fire entry point on any app where you can refresh individual pages, which is all apps, I think. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you don't have a top-level controller that runs before any others in the app, you could either add a top-level route and resolve the the endpoint similar to the accepted answer, or you could add an `app.run(...)` block after your app definition.

Answer (score 1):

I see you haven't used any **$resource**'s here, but I'm hoping you have a good understanding of them:

in **factories/delay-resource.js**:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myApp').factory('delayResource', ['$resource', '$q',
function($resource, $q){
    var _methods = ['query', 'get', 'delete', 'remove', 'save'];

    var shallowClearAndCopy = function(src, dst) {
            dst = dst || {};

            angular.forEach(dst, function(value, key){
                delete dst[key];
            });

            for (var key in src) {
                if (src.hasOwnProperty(key) && !(key.charAt(0) === '$' && key.charAt(1) === '$')) {
                    dst[key] = src[key];
                }
            }

            return dst;
        }

    var delayResourceFactory = function(baseUrlPromise, url, paramDefaults){
        var _baseUrlPromise = baseUrlPromise,
            _url = url,
            _paramDefaults = paramDefaults;

        var DelayResource = function(value){
            shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);
        };

        _methods.forEach(function(method){
            DelayResource[method] = function(params, successCB, errCB, progressCB){
                if (angular.isFunction(params)) {
                    progressCB = successCB;
                    errCB = errHandlers;
                    successCB = params;
                    errHandlers = params = null;
                }
                else if (!params || angular.isFunction(params)){
                    progressCB = errCB;
                    errCB = successCB;
                    successCB = errHandlers;
                    params = {};
                }

                var _makeResultResource = function(url){
                    var promise = $resource(url, _paramDefaults)[method](params);

                        (promise.$promise || promise).then(
                            function successHandler(){
                                var data = arguments[0];

                                if (isInstance){
                                    if (angular.isArray(data))
                                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                                            data[i] = new DelayResource(data[i])
                                    else if (angular.isObject(data))
                                        data = new DelayResource(data)
                                }

                                successCB.apply(successCB, arguments)
                                resultDelay.resolve.apply(resultDelay.resolve, arguments)
                            },
                            function(err){
                                errCB.apply(errCB, arguments)
                                resultDelay.reject.apply(resultDelay.reject, args)
                            },
                            function(){
                                progressCB.apply(progressCB, arguments)
                                resultDelay.notify.apply(resultDelay.notify, arguments)
                            }
                        )
                }

                var isInstance = this instanceof DelayResource,
                    resultDelay = $q.defer();

                if (!angular.isString(_baseUrlPromise) && angular.isFunction(_baseUrlPromise.then))
                    _baseUrlPromise.then(
                        function successCb(apiObj){
                            _makeResultResource(apiObj.RESTAPIURL + _url)
                        },
                        function successCb(){
                            throw 'ERROR - ' + JSON.stringify(arguments, null, 4)
                        })
                else
                    _makeResultResource(_baseUrlPromise.RESTAPIURL + _url);

                return resultDelay.promise;
            };


            DelayResource.prototype['$' + method] = function(){
                var value = DelayResource[method].apply(DelayResource[method], arguments);
                return value.$promise || value;
            }
        });

        return DelayResource;
    }

    return delayResourceFactory;
}]);
```

This will be the base factory that all requests to that REST API server will go through.

Then we need a **factories/api-resource.js**:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('apiResource', ['delayResource', 'api', function (delayResource, api) {
    return function (url, params) {
        return delayResource(api.URL(), url, params);
    };
}])
```

Now all factories created will just have to call the apiResource to get a handle on a resource that will communicate with the REST API

Then in a file like **factories/account-factory.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AuthRoute', ['apiResource', 'api', function (apiResource, api) {
     return apiResource(api.AUTH);
}]);
```

Now in **factories/auth-service.js**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('AuthService', ['$q', 'AuthRoute', 'NotificationService', function ($q, AuthRoute, api, NotificationService) {
    function _get(creds) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        AuthRoute.get()
            .then(
                function successCb(results){
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                },
                function errCb(){
                    // cant remember what comes into this function
                    // but handle your error appropriately here

                    //NotificationService.redirect(status);
                    //deferred.reject(data, status);
                }
            );

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        get:_get
    };
}]);
```

As you can imagine, I haven't been able to test it yet, but this is the basis. I'm going to try create a scenario that will allow me to test this. In the mean time, feel free to ask questions or point out mistakes made

**Late Addition**
Forgot to add this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('api', ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
  var restApiObj,
      promise;

  function _getConfiguration() {
    if (restApiObj)
      return restApiObj;

    if (promise)
      return promise;

    promise = $http.get('/scripts/constants/config.json')
        .then(function (data) {
          restApiObj = data;
          promise = null;
          return data;
        },
        function (data, status) {
          restApiObj = null;
          promise = null;
        });
    return promise;
  }

  return {
    URL: _getConfiguration
  }
}]);
```

**Continuing with the ui-router scenario**

```
.state('member-list', {
    url: '/members?limit=&skip='
    templateUrl: '/views/members/list.html',
    controller: 'MemberListCtrl',
    resolve:{
      members: ['$stateParams', 'MembersLoader', function($stateParams,MembersLoader){
        return MembersLoader({skip: $stateParams.skip || 0, limit: $stateParams.limit || 10});
      }       
    }
 });
```

**factory**

```
.factory('MemberRoute', ['apiResource', function(apiResource){
    return apiResource('/members/:id', { id: '@id' });
}])
.factory('MembersLoader', ['MembersRoute', function(MembersRoute){
    return function(params){
        return MemberRoute.query(params);
    };
}])
.factory('MemberFollowRoute', ['apiResource', 'api', function(apiResource, api){
    return apiResource(api.FOLLOW_MEMBER, { id: '@id' });
}])
```

**controller**

```
.controller('MemberListCtrl', ['$scope', 'members', 'MemberRoute', 'MemberFollowRoute', function($scope, members, MemberRoute, MemberFollowRoute){
    $scope.members = members;

    $scope.followMember = function(memberId){
        MemberFollowRoute.save(
            { id: memberId },
            function successCb(){
                //Handle your success, possibly with notificationService
            },
            function errCb(){
                // error, something happened that doesn't allow you to follow memberId
                //handle this, possibly with notificationService
            }
        )
    };

    $scope.unfollowMember = function(memberId){
        MemberFollowRoute.delete(
            { id: memberId },
            function successCb(){
                //Handle your success, possibly with notificationService
            },
            function errCb(){
                // error, something happened that doesn't allow you to unfollow memberId
                //handle this, possibly with notificationService
            }
        )
    };
}]);
```

With all this code above, you will never need to do any sort of initialization on app start, or in some abstract root state. If you were to destroy your API config every 5 mins, there would be no need to manually re-initialize that object and hope that something isn't busy or in need of it while you fetch the config again.

Also, if you look at MembersRoute factory, the apiResource abstracts/obscures the api.URL() that you were hoping not to have to change everywhere. So now, you just provide the url that you want to make your request to, (eg: /members/:id or api.AUTH) and never have to worry about api.URL() again :)

Comment: Oh, I also need to look into how a person adds request headers to the $resource

Comment: I am finally reading your answer. With a fresh cup of coffee. it's interesting!

Comment: @toddmo I've added a use case scenario to the code required to show the benefits ...

Comment: @GavinvanGent the way you're using : `var deferred = $q.defer();` is an antipattern. Just use the promise returned from $http.get. An example would be in my answer - the api factory

Comment: @sirrocco I've made the change. Thanks for finding this anti pattern amongst all that code.